# SQL Server date dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I want to know what is the proper statement to pull the previous year and quarter.

```
DECLARE @myvalue DATE = '2016-01-01'
```

The columns are:

- `previous_year_and_quarter_num`: data type `smallint` and is numeric representation of the previous quarter and year corresponding to the Calendar Date, expressed as an integer, e.g. `20113` for a current date in the fourth quarter of 2011.
- `previous_year_and_month_abbr`: data type `varchar(30)` and is an alpha-numeric representation of the previous quarter and year corresponding to the Calendar Date, expressed as an integer, e.g. `2011 Q3` for a current date in the fourth quarter of 2011.

Could you please help me how to write SQL statement in SQL Server.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us an example of something you have tried? It might be that you're close and we can show you how to correct it.

Comment: `WHERE previous_year_and_quarter_num >= YEAR(DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())) * 100 + DATEPART(quarter, DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()))` maybe?

Comment: I use this query to return previous_year_and_quarter but i think it is not correct   SELECT YEAR(@myval) -1  and for previous_year_and_month_abbr  i use this query:   Datename(year, @myval) + '  ' +  datename(month, @myval)  this query does not give the previous month and year corresponding to the Calendar Date. For example, November 2011 for a current date in December, 2011

Comment: can you please help me with  previous_year_and_month_abbr (i.e For example, November 2011 for a current date in December, 2011

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
declare @myvalue date = '2016-01-01'

declare @lastQuarter date = dateadd(qq,-1,@myvalue)

select concat(year(@lastQuarter),datepart(qq,@lastQuarter))
-- 20154

select concat(year(@lastQuarter),' Q',datepart(qq,@lastQuarter))
-- 2015 Q4
```

for the previous month

```
declare @myvalue date = '2016-01-01'

declare @lastMonth date = dateadd(mm,-1,@myvalue)

select @lastMonth
-- 2015-12-01

select concat(year(@lastMonth),datepart(qq,@lastMonth))
-- 20154

select concat(year(@lastMonth),' Q',datepart(qq,@lastMonth))
-- 2015 Q4
```

Check the datepart docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Update:**

Display the previous month:

```
select datename(mm,dateadd(mm,-1,@myvalue))
-- December
```

**Update 2:**

Display the week number:

```
select datepart(wk, '2021-12-31')
-- 53

-- iso week option

select datepart(isowk, '2021-12-31')
-- 52
```

Read about iso week in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Comment: Thank you.  for the previous month I want to display only the the previous month like December in this case

Comment: @johnny check the update.

Comment: I've changed the update using @myvalue. Let me know if it's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks it worked.  But I have another issue with another column.  week_of_year .  the wuery i have return 53 for '2021-12-31' and the column has check add constraint  validation rule check week_of_year >=1 and week_of_year <=52. How will i have only 52 weeks.   Query:    DECLARE @MYVAL DATE = '2021-12-31'   SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @MYVAL).  By doing this, i have an error constraint violation.  Please could you help me?

Comment: You have to check that logic, WEEK and ISO_WEEK are in this interval [1, 53]

Comment: Is there a way to do it programmatically or  should I talk to the DBA to change the validation rule?

Comment: You can use select case when else end

Comment: I use this query:  select (wk, @myval)  but the data shows  that every month of December for each year has 53 weeks  which is wrong.  Could you please help me build the case statement. I am new in SQL server. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this `select case when datepart(wk, @date) < 53 then datepart(wk, @date) else 1 end`. Remember to validate this logic with your dba.

Comment: The DBA has changed the logic  for the constraint validation  rule to <=53. So in this regard, I am fine. The issue I have is  that it shows that the  year 2021 being 53 weeks. 2021 has 52 weeks.  Here is the code I am using. datepart(week, @myval). What am i missing? Please help.

Comment: @johnny check the update.

Comment: i am working on to ca;culate the fiscal month number and fiscal month name in SQL SERVER. i Have this query which give me the fiscal month number   Declare @myval Date = 2021-11-01'  select month(dateadd(M, -3, @myval))  the result is 8 which is correct. The fiscal month number of November is 8.  But i am struggling to display the fiscal month name (i.e Novembr). I could not figure it out. Could you please help? Thank you